# Simple example of Bootstrap 3 and Typeahead

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead.js

I have this simple implementation that works for typeahead and jQuery but when I enter something into the  control I see [object Object] instead of the actual values.

How can I fix this so I see the stateName?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="examples.css">
  <title>Example of Twitter Typeahead</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script  type="text/javascript" src="typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log("Ready!"); 

        $('#search').typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 1
        },
        {
            name: 'states',
            displayKey: 'value',
            source: function (query, process) {
            states = [];
            map = {};

            var data = [
                {"stateCode": "CA", "stateName": "California"},
                {"stateCode": "AZ", "stateName": "Arizona"},
                {"stateCode": "NY", "stateName": "New York"},
                {"stateCode": "NV", "stateName": "Nevada"},
                {"stateCode": "OH", "stateName": "Ohio"}
            ];

            $.each(data, function (i, state) {
                map[state.stateName] = state;
                states.push(state.stateName);
            });

            process(states);
        },
        matcher: function (item) {
            if (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.trim().toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                return true;
            }
        },
        sorter: function (items) {
            return items.sort();
        },
        highlighter: function (item) {
            var regex = new RegExp( '(' + this.query + ')', 'gi' );
            return item.replace( regex, "<strong>$1</strong>" );
        },
        updater: function (item) {
            selectedState = map[item].stateCode;
            return item;
        }
        });
    });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="States of USA">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is what the screen looks like when I enter a value to be searched for in the  control.

[image]

Comment: `displayKey: 'value',` is probably wrong

Comment: Is this your full code? I'm seeing a syntax error at 'matcher'. Maybe I'm reading it wrong, but I don't think it's inside an object.

Comment: this is the complete code.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find reference to a `matcher` param anywhere in the typeahead docs.

According to same docs, the `source` function should:

> compute the suggestion set (i.e. an array of JavaScript objects) for query and then invoke cb with said set

Your code is trying to filter the data in a matcher function passed as an argument to typeahead and your source function is returning all elements. The matcher function is never even called. I removed it and created it as a standalone function. I call it inside the source function so that source only returns matching results. This fixes the filtering.

Typeahead would still show `undefined` instead of the state name, that is because it expects the data it receives from the source function to be an array of objects, and it shows each object's `value` field. I changed that too.

`highlighter` and `sorter` parameters are useless too.

This is the changed JS:

```
 function  matcher (item, query) {
        if (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.trim().toLowerCase()) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
    }

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("Ready!"); 


    $('#search').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
    },
    {
        name: 'states',
        displayKey: 'value',
        source: function (query, process) {
        states = [];
        map = {};

        var data = [
            {"stateCode": "CA", "stateName": "California"},
            {"stateCode": "AZ", "stateName": "Arizona"},
            {"stateCode": "NY", "stateName": "New York"},
            {"stateCode": "NV", "stateName": "Nevada"},
            {"stateCode": "OH", "stateName": "Ohio"}
        ];

        $.each(data, function (i, state) {
            map[state.stateName] = state;
    if(matcher(state.stateName, query)) {
        states.push({value: state.stateName});
    }
        });

        process(states);
    },

    });
});
```

Or check the jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/kayev/1